# Retrieving Msgpack from Http request in java

Tags: java, android, msgpack

I am trying to retrieve a msgpack object sent by my rails server in an AsyncTask.

Rails controller - Rails

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: data.to_json }
      format.msgpack { render msgpack: data.to_msgpack }
end
```

AsyncTask - Java

```
        HttpEntity messageEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (messageEntity != null) {
                MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                messageEntity.writeTo(baos);
                byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

                msgpack.read(bytes);    

                [...]
            }
```

My object is like the following one

```
{
    "aspects": {
        "1438166757890": {
            "deleted": "0",
            "name": "Choc",
            "updated": "1438166757889"
        },
    [...]
    },
    "items": {
        "1438166757872": {
            "aspects": [
                1438166757890,
                1438166757905,
                1438166757929,
                1438166757947,
                1438166757964,
                1438166757980,
                1438166757997
            ],
            "deleted": "0",
            "name": "OTHER",
            "updated": "1438166757872"
        },
    [...]
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to read it with my `msgpack` object like this

`Value v = msgpack.read(bytes);`

I have this error

`java.io.IOException: Invalid byte: -39`

Or when I am using those kind of templates

`Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<String, String>>> v = msgpack.read(bytes, k);`

I am getting

`org.msgpack.MessageTypeException: Unexpected array value`
or
`org.msgpack.MessageTypeException: Unexpected map value`

I did not find any good documentation on Stack or Google concerning this way to read. The official Msgpack website serialize and deserialize a `List<String>`

```
List<String> src = new ArrayList<String>();
src.add("msgpack");
src.add("kumofs");
src.add("viver");

MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();

byte[] raw = msgpack.write(src);

Value dynamic = msgpack.read(raw);
List<String> dst2 = new Converter(dynamic)
    .read(Templates.tList(Templates.TString));
```

Did someone already had this problem and if so how to manage Msgpack templates in java ?

*Edit :*

Stacktrace when I am using `msgpack.read(bytes);` without templates :

```
W/System.err( 2999): java.io.IOException: Invalid byte: -39
W/System.err( 2999): at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readOneWithoutStackLarge(MessagePackUnpacker.java:323)
W/System.err( 2999): at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readOneWithoutStack(MessagePackUnpacker.java:139)
W/System.err( 2999): at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readOne(MessagePackUnpacker.java:73)
W/System.err( 2999): at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readValue(MessagePackUnpacker.java:559)
W/System.err( 2999): at org.msgpack.unpacker.AbstractUnpacker.readValue(AbstractUnpacker.java:65)
W/System.err( 2999): at org.msgpack.MessagePack.read(MessagePack.java:297)
W/System.err( 2999): at org.msgpack.MessagePack.read(MessagePack.java:283)
```

And when I am using

```
Template<Map<String, String>> map2 = Templates.tMap(Templates.TString, Templates.TString);

Map<String, String> v = msgpack.read(bytes, map2);
```

Stacktrace :

```
W/System.err( 1510): org.msgpack.MessageTypeException: Unexpected array value
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.unpacker.Accept.acceptArray(Accept.java:79)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readOneWithoutStackLarge(MessagePackUnpacker.java:264)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readOneWithoutStack(MessagePackUnpacker.java:139)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readOne(MessagePackUnpacker.java:73)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readString(MessagePackUnpacker.java:472)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.StringTemplate.read(StringTemplate.java:46)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.StringTemplate.read(StringTemplate.java:25)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.AbstractTemplate.read(AbstractTemplate.java:31)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.MapTemplate.read(MapTemplate.java:72)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.MapTemplate.read(MapTemplate.java:27)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.AbstractTemplate.read(AbstractTemplate.java:31)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.MapTemplate.read(MapTemplate.java:72)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.MapTemplate.read(MapTemplate.java:27)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.AbstractTemplate.read(AbstractTemplate.java:31)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.MapTemplate.read(MapTemplate.java:72)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.MapTemplate.read(MapTemplate.java:27)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.template.AbstractTemplate.read(AbstractTemplate.java:31)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.MessagePack.read(MessagePack.java:510)
W/System.err( 1510): at org.msgpack.MessagePack.read(MessagePack.java:479)
```

Comment: Could you please post stacktraces of the exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @naXa analysis, I decided to find another msgpack repo on git. After some research, I found [MessagePack for Java](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java).

Files extracted, I used `sbt` to build my `.jar` files from there with the command `./sbt publish local`.

Once build finished, I had main, source and javadoc `.jar` files into the following dir : `~/msgpack-java-07-develop/msgpack-core/target`.

I imported all my `.jar` files in my Eclipse project, changed the build path and then, to retrieve my `msgpack` content, I could wrote those simple lines to get my Map containing my values :

```
HttpEntity messageEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

if (messageEntity != null) {
    MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();

    MessageUnpacker u = msgpack.newUnpacker(messageEntity.getContent());
    MapValue mv = (MapValue) u.unpackValue();

    Map<Value, Value> map = mv.map();
```

Comment: Can you please let me know the version of the message pack library you have used. I am working on a gradle based project and have used 0.8.11 version. new MessagePack();  gives error saying that this constructor is private.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer! Just a little analysis.

Here is [the class](https://github.com/ProgVal/msgpack-java-android-fixes/blob/master/src/main/java/org/msgpack/unpacker/MessagePackUnpacker.java) and the code from where the `IOException` is thrown

```
default:
    // System.out.println("unknown b "+(b&0xff));
    // headByte = CS_INVALID
    headByte = REQUIRE_TO_READ_HEAD;
    throw new IOException("Invalid byte: " + b); // TODO error FormatException
}
```

My guess is that msgpack for Android is outdated and doesn't know a type with code `-39 (-0x27)`. Check the differences in types between [msgpack for Android](https://github.com/ProgVal/msgpack-java-android-fixes) and msgpack that you use on server side.

A `-` in `-39` looks suspicious too..